# rpmbuild - delete source files before final bundle is built

Tags: linux, aws-lambda, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm working with `rpmbuild` in `AWS Lambda` which has a storage limit of 512MB and it's running out of disk space.

I'd like to remove the original files/assets to free up space after the file `/tmp/rpm-tmp.XXXX` has been created and before the final `.rpm` bundle is generated.

Is it possible?

Comment: Were you able to run rpmbuild on Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `%prep` you have an opportunity to delete the source archive files. This can get ugly and is definitely not something a user will expect.

At the end of `%build` you have a chance to delete all the intermediate files.

None of this can easily be automated, so you'll have to tweak your spec file to do what you need.

Comment: Nit pick: "make install" will usually regenerate the intermediate files removed in %build. Sure you can avoid "make install" and do the same operations manually, but it's almost certainly easier to create a build VM with enough storage space.